# Unable to configure Patch Request in React

Tags: reactjs, rest

I'm building an Outlook Add-In and trying to update calendar events using a patch request (Outlook REST API). I am getting a 404, I suspect something having to do with how I get the event ID. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the code :

```
  updateEvent = (id) => {
    axios.patch(`/v2.0/me/events/${id}`,
      {
        Start: {
          DateTime: this.props.currentValues
        }
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
      })
  }
```

Comment: Did you check if the API requires any specific headers? Content-Type maybe?

Comment: Where do I add headers in a post request, can you tell me the syntax?